# Pattern fill for raster contours in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, contour

How do I fill the area within raster contours with a pattern fill, instead of colors in QGIS? Is this even possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "raster contours"? Contour lines (vectors) were created from Rasters? Or your data are rasters?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your area you could convert your contour lines into polygons and then colour them using a patterned fill.  This might be very slow on a large area with lots of contours.  I've tested it using a simple fill on a small area:

[image: Filled contour example]

Because the polygons will overlap each other you would have to use symbol levels to stack them correctly (See section 2.8 of this: http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/basic_map/symbology.html).